# Array out of text in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So let's say I have a String that looks like this: `"apple, banana, orange"`. How do i split the text to get a Array that looks like this `"apple", "banana", "orange"`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is well-documented; have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: PHP provides the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function exactly for this purpose. And the [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove the unwanted whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: Voted to close this because it's unlikely this question will be helpfull to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use the explode PHP function :)

```
 <?php
    $str = "apple, banana, orange";
    print_r (explode(" ",$str));

 ?>
```

Comment: Yes, the space will work but exploding on the comma is probably what the OP meant.

Comment: Shouldn't you explode the comma as well? :)

Comment: $a = explode("," ,"apple, banana, orange");

array_walk($result, function(&$element) { 
         $element = '"'.$element.'"';
}, $a);

print_r($result);